# How do I determine what modules an OCaml library provides?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I'm just starting a project to analyze C programs using [goblint-cil](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/goblint-cil/).

I know I needed to use a library to import it. The [README](https://github.com/goblint/cil) for goblint-cil says the following:

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "goblint-cil";;
# GoblintCil.cilVersion;;
- : string = "2.0.3"
```

I then made a dune file requiring it:

```
(executable
  (libraries goblint-cil)
  (name main))
```

I have two basic questions about libraries in Ocaml:

1. How do I find out what modules a library or package provides? In the case of `GoblintCil` it was right there in the README, but I would like to know if this library provides any other modules.
2. What is the relation between libraries, packages, and modules? It seems to me the following are true:

- Every .ml file forms a module by capitalizing it
- Packages are just a collection of libraries and (potentially empty) set of executables
- Libraries are a sub-collection of modules in a package

Are these correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- read the documentation of the package:

  - online at [ocaml.org](https://ocaml.org), for instance, https://ocaml.org/p/goblint-cil/latest/doc/index.html.
  - locally, by generating documentation for your installed packages with [odig](https://erratique.ch/software/odig).
- In a toplevel, once you have loaded a library with `#require "library_name"`, you can `#show` its toplevel module:

```
#require "base";;
#show Base;;
```